# Push data from websocket server to client

Tags: websocket, push

Websockets are hailed as a bi-directional process. However, whilst there are hundreds of websocket code examples on the web, they all require a request from the client(browser) to the server to get the data (like an echo server or chat).

So far, I have not found any code which will send new data (originating at the server end) to the client via an open websocket. Ideally, I would like to use a node.js server but I'm open to alternatives. Any ideas?

Comment: Typically, you need to have a pub-sub protocol over WebSocket, so that you can push real-time data from the server to the client at any time when they originate. A ready-made solution to achieve this is lightstreamer.com (full disclosure: I work for Lightstreamer).

Comment: Thanks for the comment re pub-sub. Don't know anything about the subject, so I'll look into it. However, it looks like overkill, bearing in mind that the server is already talking to the client. I just need to tell it what to say and when to say it.

Comment: If you already have an open websocket between the client and the server, you can simply push whatever data you want, and when you want, from the server to the client. The client will need to listen for incoming data on the websocket and process them accordingly. Pub-sub is needed when the client should be able to request what data it wants to receive (that is, express interest in subjects). But if this is predefined, you can push your data directly.

Comment: With regard to Pub-Sub, it may not be suitable for my current project, but for future reference , what would be a typical latency between a publisher sending  a small data object and it being received by the client. I realise that there are many variables, but i'm just trying to work out the potential uses.

Comment: It mainly depends on network latency. So, if the WebSocket server is efficient, depending on where it is located in the world you may expect a latency in the order of 5-200 ms.

Comment: Thanks, I'll run some 'proof of concept' tests

Comment: @AlessandroAlinone you say "If you already have an open websocket between the client and the server, you can simply push whatever data you want, and when you want, from the server to the client"- could you share a code snippet for how to do this? I believe that would answer the OPs question.

Comment: Were you able to do it eventually ? If yes, can you share a sample code snippet for reference here ? @Robbie